# Ionic 2 Emulator

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to launch my app in an emulator but Im getting lots of generic console errors as if it were in a browser... anyone got any clue why this is this is one of the errors

```
console.warn: Native: tried calling Facebook.login, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

and this is the command I am using, the desired outcome is having livereload in the device and also having it emulated.. at the moment it acts as though it is in a browser and outputs the above error when I try to use facebook authentication

ionic emulate ios "--port" "8000" "--address" "192.168.56.1" "--liveReloadPort" "8000" "--nobrowser" "--consolelogs" "--serverlogs" -l

Answer (score 0):

Any changes to plugins will  require a full rebuild. So if you have added `Facebook` plugin after live reload try rebuilding.

Comment: Yeah I have been rebuilding it loads of times, Ive added the access control headers etc to the config.xml - is it an issue with IOS 9 ? I have read some stuff but its all very hazy

Comment: did you try ``ionic state reset --plugins``